# basic javascript , multiple else if giving unexpected output

Tags: javascript

```
function getRankForScore(score){
         if(score <= 20)        return 1;
    else if(21 < score <=40)    return 2;
    else if(41 < score <=60)    return 3;
    else if(61 < score <=90)    return 4;
    else return 5;
}
```

`getRankForScore(10)` // Returns `1` ,expected

`getRankForScore(22)` //Returns `2` , expected

But

`getRankForScore(50 or any number > 21)` // Returns `2` .

How can i use switch case construct for something like inequality checks ?
What is wrong with the above function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a oneliner here, using [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
function getRankForScore(score){
 return score <= 20 && 1 || score <=40 && 2 || 
        score <= 60 && 3 || score <=90 && 4 || 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks . BTW its score <= 60 , please edit . Solution is really simple

Answer (score 7):

Because

when when you enter number greater than 21 the condition `21 < score` evaluates to true and returns 1 which is then compared with 40, which is obviously less than 40

Answer (score 4):

Your syntax was wrong in the else if's:

```
function getRankForScore(score){
    if(score <= 20)         return 1;
    else if(score <= 40)    return 2;
    else if(score <= 60)    return 3;
    else if(score <= 90)    return 4;
    else return 5;
}
```

Comment: Thmbs up for the least redundant notation.

Answer (score 2):

`a < b < c` is not what you expect, it is interpreted as `(a < b) < c` which becomes (for example) `true < c`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRankForScore(score) {
    var result;

    switch(true) {
       case score <= 20:
           result = 1;
           break;
       case score > 21 && score <= 40:
           result = 2;
           break;
       case score > 41 && score <= 60:
           result = 3;
           break;
       case score > 61 && score <= 90:
           result = 4;
           break;
      default:
           result = 5;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a code like:

```
function getRankForScore(score) {
    if(score <= 20) {
        return 1;
    } else if(score > 21 && score <= 40) {
        return 2;
    } else if(score > 41 && score <= 60) {
        return 3;
    } else if(score > 61 && score <= 90) {
        return 4;
    } else {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function getRankForScore(score){
         if(score <= 20)        return 1;
    else if(score >21 && score <=40)    return 2;
    else if(score > 41 && score <=60)    return 3;
    else if(score> 61 && score <=90)    return 4;
    else return 5;
}
```

The expression `if (a < b < c)` is not leagal.

Answer (score 0):

That's why:

```
function getRankForScore(score){
         if(score <= 20)        return 1;
    else if(score > 21 && score <= 40)    return 2;
    else if(score > 41 && score <= 60)    return 3;
    else if(score > 62 && score <= 80)    return 4;
    else return 5;
}

alert(getRankForScore(42));
```

Javascript sometimes is not math :(

You can't do 21 < score <= 40, you must use && statement.

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BaJse/

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you write something like this:

```
if(21 < score <=40)
```

it actually equals to:

```
if (21 < score || score <= 40)
```

which fits your condition. of any number bigger than 21 - and that is why it doesn't go on checking your other if statements.

you should do an AND statement:

```
if (21 < score && score <= 40)
```